# set multiple IP address point to single domain name in gwan server

Tags: configuration, listener, g-wan, virtual-hosts

Who can explain how to set multi internet IP point to a single domain in gwan server?
How to set the listeners and vhosts in gwan server?
For example, abc.com are pointed by
123.456.345.34, and 345.567.789.56, and 123.123.123.112 and ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read http://gwan.ch/faq#listener you can see the answer.
If you want to use on gwan server instance, just use /gwan/0.0.0.0_80/$abc.com
The 0.0.0.0 will listen on port 80 to all ip addresses set on your system.
It's the simplest and most flexible solution.

But why do you have 3 ip addresses for the same domain? Normally this is used when you have three different server answering on round robin, or other high availability configuration...

And you know that ip addresses end on 255 right ;)

Comment: thanks for your answer. You are right that numbers in IPv4 address should not be greater than 255.